# Docker container can't be started In Plesk on CentOS Linux 7.9.2009

Tags: docker, centos, plesk

Plesk Obsidian Version 18.0.35 /
CentOS Linux 7.9.2009 /
Docker version 20.10.6, build 370c289 /

Docker container with MySQL stopped today and can't be started.
Trying to start docker container in Plesk I am getting the error:

```
Error: {"message":"OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:76: mounting \"/var/lib/docker/containers/23385a006794b8bd06cb112d5a9c8401d6bb78370e6e7e6adea8182b2205c624/resolv.conf\" to rootfs at \"/etc/resolv.conf\" caused: mount through procfd: possibly malicious path detected -- refusing to operate on /etc/resolv.conf: unknown"}
```

We tried to install another container - same error
We deleted the container and the docker App in Plesk and installed all from zero - same error.

$docker info

[image]

Comment: We downgrading containerd.io  from 1.4.6-3.1.el7  to 1.4.4-3.1.el7 and now the docker container works. But unfortunately is not possible to create a new nysql server in Plesk

Error: The test connection to the database server has failed because of network problems:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away

Comment: just got the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading docker-ce and nvidia-docker can solve the problem！

Encountered this problem in centos7.2.1511. I solved it by adjusting the docker version.

Available environment in centos7.2.1511
docker-ce-19.03.1-3.el7.x86_64（note：docker-ce-19.03.4+ is not available）
nvidia-docker2-2.6.0-1.noarch

Please forgive me bad english！！

Comment: Thank you, we  just changed the entire server, not it runs on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue with the static docker install version 20.10.10 on RHEL 7.1.  The problem turned out to be the permissions on the "data-root" directory, if unspecified it will be /var/lib/docker.

The system I installed on had a RAM or tmpfs "root" / filesystem which isn't ideal for the data-root directory, so I created a directory on an attached drive, but the permissions of the newly created directory didn't meet the requirements of docker, which appear to need execution for all user, group, and other. i.e.

drwx--x--x. user group 6 Nov 11 10:54 /var/lib/docker

The directory was created with "710" permissions (as in chmod 710), but once changed to "711" (example: chmod 711 /var/lib/docker), the problem went away.

Just make sure that the "data-root" location has appropriate permissions for your setup.  The "data-root" location can be changed by providing --data-root /path to the dockerd process or adding it to /etc/docker/daemon.json

More details can be found below:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).